# MongoBb - Aggregation step to project elements from matching nested array document to root document level

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I've the following structure of documents in MongoDB. The array records contain different persons that have the roles teacher or student.

```
[
    {_id: 1, persons: [{role:"teacher", name: "Mark", school: "", county: "Oneida"}, {role:"student", name: "John", school: "LM High School", county:""}]},
    {_id: 2, persons: [{role:"teacher", name: "Robert", school: "", county: "Onondaga"}, {role:"student", name: "David", school: "Beaker High School", county:""}}]}
]
```

I need to get the output in the following format. From the first matching teacher person I need to select county, and from the first matching student person I need to select the school. I need to project both school and county from the nested array element level to the root document level.

```
[
    {_id: 1, county: "Oneida", school: "LM High School"},
    {_id: 2, county: "Onondaga", school: "Beaker High School"}
]
```

What can be the appropriate aggregation step? I tried several steps like arrayElemAt, projection, etc. but couldn't get the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `persons` array and filter teachers and students separately
- to get the first element from the array, use `$first` from MongoDB 4.4, for below you can use `$arrayElemAt`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      teacher: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$persons",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.role", "teacher"] }
        }
      },
      student: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$persons",
          cond: { $eq: ["$$this.role", "student"] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      county: { $first: "$teacher.county" },
      school: { $first: "$student.school" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/P2c2yKRKmf0)

Comment: Thank you! For the second step $first didn't work for me. I had to use something like county: { $arrayElemAt: ["$teacher.county",0] }

Comment: okay, $first will work from mongodb v4.4.